# How to make better slow falling? Fabric 1.17

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I want to make a custom status/potion effect that is just slow falling but you fall slower, how do I do this? I looked through all of the vanilla files but the data for slow falling is nowhere...

Comment: What did you tried ? Where are you stuck exactly ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. My problem is that I want to make a new potion effect. I want to make slow falling, but it makes the player fall even slower than vanilla slow falling, it's super slow falling basically. I tried to copy off the vanilla files for slow falling, but that didn't work as slow falling wasn't anywhere.

Comment: Why don't just use with more level or just change default effect values ?

Comment: Because I have no idea how to get the default values.